# SQL*Net configuration - spurious IP

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

I can't connect to my Oracle 12 database through sql*net

Tracing it backwards my tnsping result is as follows:

```
tnsping devpdb

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 08-OCT-2014 05:28:55

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:

Used HOSTNAME adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XX.XXX.XXX.XX)(PORT=1521)))
```

The host IP is unresolvable from this computer.  I don't know where it is getting this from it's not the NAT address of this host or of the router, it's at least 30 hops away per ping.

tnsnames.ora:

```
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEVDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = tts-PowerEdge-T105)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = devDB)
    )
  )

DEVPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = tts-PowerEdge-T105)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = devpdb)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = devpdb)
    )
  )
DIAMONDPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = tts-PowerEdge-T105)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = DIAMONDPDB)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = DIAMONDPDB)
    )
  )
```

The /etc/hosts is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.1.2 tts-PowerEdge-T105

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

ping works:

ping tts-PowerEdge-T105
   PING tts-PowerEdge-T105 (192.168.1.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from tts-PowerEdge-T105 (192.168.1.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms

my sqlnet.ora:

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, ONAMES, HOSTNAME)
```

When I change tnsnames.ora as follows:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEVDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = tts-PowerEdge-T105)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = devDB)
    )
  )

DEVPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = tts-PowerEdge-T105)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = devpdb)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = devpdb)
    )
  )
DIAMONDPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.2)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = DIAMONDPDB)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = DIAMONDPDB)
    )
  )

WTF =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.2)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = WTF)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = WTF)
    )
  )
```

I get this:

```
tnsping wtf

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 08-OCT-2014 08:21:15

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

my environment:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib
ORACLE_SID=devDB
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
```

I can even remove my tnsnames.ora file and get the original message so it is not being used.

I tried changing my sqlnet.ora to:

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File:      /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

#NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, ONAMES, HOSTNAME)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (HOSTNAME,TNSNAMES, ONAMES)
```

and it makes no difference

So whatever the HOSTNAME adapter is or how it is configured seems to be the problem. Note that "Used parameter files:" is empty

I exported TNS_ADMIN

```
export TNS_ADMIN=/home/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/network/admin
```

but still no parameter files are being used. I have read permissions on the file.

I suspect it has something to do with my sqlnet.ora file, but I have run out of ideas.

Comment: Very interesting. I'm not skilled in administering Oracle under Linux, but clearly, first you have to force your Linux user to use a specific `sqlnet.ora` file. Instead of exporting the `TNS_ADMIN` variable try exporting `ORACLE_HOME` with the value of `/home/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1`, also make sure that the `/home/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1` is accessible by the user which you use to tnsping the listener. Set up the `sqlnet.ora` so that `TNSNAMES` is the first in `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH`.

Comment: So the xx.xxx.xxx.xx is an IP address that you don't recognise, or a FQDN you can't resolve? Your files claim to be in `/u01/...`, but where are they really - you set TNS_ADMIN to `/home/u01/...`? Is `devpdb` resolvable to an IP, via dig or nslookup? It looks like TNS_ADMIN isn't set to a valid path and it doesn't use the default path, and happens to be using an alias that is also a host...

Comment: It was a permissions problem.  The user could not read the file.

The files were really where they were supposed to be. I didn't have to set TNS_ADMIN.  I didn't install the database but a 

   chown oracle sqlnet.ora tnsnames.ora 

and 

   chmod 644 sqlnet.ora tnsnames.ora 

did the trick.

Thanks for trying.